# df.str.get_dummies() vs pd.get_dummies() (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series like so:

```
0 mcdonalds, popeyes
1 wendys
2 popeyes
3 mcdonalds
4 mcdonalds
```

I use the following code:

```
df.str.get_dummies(sep = ', ')
```

to get the following data frame:

```
popeyes wendys mcdonalds
1       0      1
0       1      0
1       0      0
0       0      1
0       0      1
```

I want to remove a column though to account for the dummy variable trap. how do i do this like in the drop_first argument in [pd.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)?

expected output might look something like this, but i don't want to hardcode to drop a random column:

```
popeyes wendys 
1       0      
0       1      
1       0      
0       0      
0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explode your `Series` before using `pd.get_dummies`:

```
>>> (pd.get_dummies(df.str.split(', ').explode(), drop_first=True)
       .groupby(level=0).max())

   popeyes  wendys
0        1       0
1        0       1
2        1       0
3        0       0
4        0       0
```

Details:

```
>>> df.str.split(', ').explode()
0    mcdonalds
0      popeyes
1       wendys
2      popeyes
3    mcdonalds
4    mcdonalds
dtype: object

>>> pd.get_dummies(df.str.split(', ').explode(), drop_first=True)
   popeyes  wendys
0        0       0
0        1       0
1        0       1
2        1       0
3        0       0
4        0       0
```

**Alternative**:

```
>>> df.str.get_dummies(sep=', ').drop(columns=df.iloc[0].split(', ')[0])

   popeyes  wendys
0        1       0
1        0       1
2        1       0
3        0       0
4        0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice to remove the first column:

```
s.str.get_dummies(', ').iloc[:, 1:]
```

Output:

```
   popeyes  wendys
0        1       0
1        0       1
2        1       0
3        0       0
4        0       0
```

Comment: This works because the first value (mcdonalds) is also the first column in lexicographical order. If you replace 'mcdonals' with 'zdonalds', it doesn't work anymore :)